# Adding audio to video produced from OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I've been using [OpenCV under python](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/index.html) to record video from a capture device. Two output AVI's are written each hour, at the top of each hour the file names are changed. One of the files is the original capture and one uses some of OpenCV's detection functions.

As always, things change and audio needs to be recorded which wasn't originally a concern. I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions about how best to do this. Current thought is to separately record the audio track using pyaudio and then use ffmpeg to mux them together after the hour has finished recording although I do have some concerns about keeping accurate lipsync.

I'm wondering if anyone has any better ideas about how to do this accurately and without noticeable gaps in the recording?

Answer (score 1):

The `pyaudio` module may fit your needs, it is a wrapper aroung portaudio. On MacOsX, this hack installs the portaudio libray:

```
svn co https://www.portaudio.com/repos/portaudio/trunk portaudio
cd portaudio/
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 -m 644 ./include/pa_mac_core.h /usr/local/include/pa_mac_core.h
sudo easy_install pyaudio
```

Check their website: http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/

Comment: Yes, pyaudio is what I've been using so far, I'm just wondering if doing both separately and then joining later on is a good solution or not

Comment: Great instructions! Fixed my original pyaudio install failures. Slight change however was to use "https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/portaudio/" as the URL since the one you provided didn't work for me.

Comment: glad it helped! I wonder if I would do it the same way 6 years later (did not type the ``svn`` command for ... years!) :-)

Answer (score 0):

As no better solutions have come up and incase its of use to anyone else, I've been going with my original plan and recording sound using PyAudio.

I'm actually using mencoder which is called using POpen with pipes for stdout and stderr, a bit of regex is then used to check that the job was successful and I'm achieving good enough results for my application although the audio is sometimes a frame or two out.

Comment: Hi Duncan!

Would you mind sharing the code for audio/video synchronised recording?

Many thanks!
Steve

Comment: Hi Steve, Afraid that although this works for short recordings the lipsync tends to drift after a few hours of running and I havnt been able to track down the reason so far.