# open a video in C# and iterate into frames and save the processed frames as another video

Tags: c#, .net, video, video-processing, emgucv

I am trying to open a video in my application to process on the frames and then save the results into another video. I used [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) ([Emgu](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/OpenCV)) for my image processing with no issues.  But I cannot use it properly for processing videos as it pops "Access Violation" exception from time to time.  Also I want to keep the audio track of the video for the output.  So I just want to iterate through the frames in simple C# code and use my Emgu function on each frame.

These are desirable for my app:

1. Keeping the audio
2. Video codec/compression support
3. Fast performance

Comment: Are you using [opencvdotnet](http://code.google.com/p/opencvdotnet/) and have you tried the [tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/opencvdotnet/wiki/Tutorial) ?

Comment: I am using emgucv but it has bugs. if you are saying that opencvdotnet works fine with videos then I surely move on using that! thanks

Comment: Opencvdotnet is no longer active. the last release was 3 years ago. you can use Emgu CV as a pure opencv wrapper by only relying on CvInvoke methods, so you will be sure you will not have more bugs than the OpenCV ones.

Answer (score 2):

Opencv is a library mainly for Computer Vision stuff and so there's no built-in function that let you process audio data.
There's a similar question with a solution here on stackoverflow:
[Adding audio to video produced from OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846634/adding-audio-to-video-produced-from-opencv)

To take advantage of FFMPEG and it's related softwares take a look here:
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FFMPEG

The Access Violation error you are facing using Emgu may be related to some emgu or opencv bugs, the 2.2 version has some known with video saving.

Comment: thanks, that was very helping. a plain c# code that iterates frames and extracts bitmap would do what I need (I will use opencv on bitmaps only).